# How to add a user defined column with a single value to a SQL query

Tags: sql

I currently have a SQL query that produces a table with around 10M rows. I would like to append this table with another column that has the same entry for all 10M rows.

As an example consider the following toy query

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_QUANTITY
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
GROUP BY SALES_DAY
```

And say that is produces the following table

```
 PRODUCT_ID ORDER_QUANTITY`     
      1          10
      2          12
      3          14
```

How can I change this query so that it produces the following table, where every entry in USER_VALUE is 999.

```
 PRODUCT_ID ORDER_QUANTITY USER_VALUE  
      1           10         999
      2           12         999
      3           14         999
```

I realize that there may be several answers here... but I suppose that it would help to know the method that would be produce the table with the smallest file size (I assume this would require specifying the type of data beforehand).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_QUANTITY, 999 as USER_VALUE
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
GROUP BY SALES_DAY
```

Comment: Does anyone know what is the `999 as USER_VALUE` substitution is called? 

I want to search for how to do this in an ORM and I want to know what to search for.

Comment: Can we also add some more custom values in order (e.g., 999, 1050, 2001) into this user-defined column?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass it in the `SELECT`, for example:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_QUANTITY, 999 AS USER_VALUE
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
GROUP BY SALES_DAY
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_QUANTITY, user_value=999
    FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
    GROUP BY SALES_DAY
```

Comment: @Vinoth_S the question doesnot have the tag for oracle. don't downvote without reading the question.