# Add user defined value to a column in an sql query

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query:

```
select DISTINCT shortname_chn from dim_channel;
```

The query returns me data for example:

```
| shortname_chn (VARCHAR)  |
|__________________________|
|       MTV                |  
|       National Geographic|
|       Discovery          | 
|       ARY News           |
```

How can I manipulate the SQL query so that I can add an additional row to the returned rows.

Following is the result I wish to get after running some query:

```
| shortname_chn (VARCHAR)  |
|__________________________|
|       MTV                |  
|       National Geographic|
|       Discovery          | 
|       ARY News           |
|       ALL                |
```

Where the last row "ALL" is user defined, not present in the database.

In the above mentioned regard, I researched and came across this question : [How to add a user defined column with a single value to a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295549/how-to-add-a-user-defined-column-with-a-single-value-to-a-sql-query) but it targets the problem of adding a whole new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT shortname_chn from dim_channel
UNION 
SELECT 'ALL'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am accepting the answer.How can I keep the "ALL" row on the top ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this by `UNION`ing with a query that returns your fake row, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            shortname_chn 

FROM        dim_channel

UNION ALL

SELECT      'ALL' AS shortname_chn
```